# I RUN A PYTHON FILE WHICH GIVES ERROR. I WANT TO COUNT THE TIME BETWEEN STARTING OF FILE AND THE ERROR

Tags: python

I RUN A PYTHON FILE WHICH GIVES ERROR. I WANT TO COUNT THE TIME BETWEEN STARTING OF FILE AND THE ERROR

Comment: Would you please give more information?

Comment: And please don't shout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Do you want to measure the time it takes to read a specific file in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the code by a `try..except` and add `time.time()` before and in the `except` to have the start and end time.

This is a code example

```
def funct():
    raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    start = time.time()

    try:
        for x in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)

        funct()

        end = time.time()
    except Exception:
        end = time.time()


    print(end-start)
```

Best regards